# Getting The output in a text file in python

Tags: python

I am writing a code to get the name of the files of a certain folder in a list by my method i'm getting it openly in the out put . I want to get the output in a text file how to do that?

```
from os import walk

dir_path = r'E://Entertainment//Movies//Hollywood'
res = []

for (dir_path, dir_names, file_names) in walk(dir_path):
    res.extend(file_names)
# print(res)

def f(res):
    yield from res

for x in f(res):
    print(x)
```

Comment: If you want to write to a file instead of printing, _do that_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `with open` context handler with "write" mode and write the `res` list as a string joined by newlines:

```py
with open('outpt.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(res))
```

More info: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
with open('some_file', 'w') as fh:
    for x in f(res):
        fh.write(f'{x}')
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing in the code. (to make it more clear to OP and other readers!)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
from os import walk

res = []

dir_path = r'.//Hollywood'
for (dir_path, dir_names, file_names) in walk(dir_path):
    res.extend(file_names)

with open('Hollywood.txt', mode='w') as f:
    for s in res:
        f.write(f'{s}\n')
```